# Android Project in Eclipse with problems of Setup Fixes

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, android-library

I have a Android project in eclipse, that depends of a " lot " of external libraries/projects:

[image]

The problem, came when I had to upgrade SDK.Libraries started to crash, android-support-v7-appcompat started with the error of resources not found.. etcc.. I fixed almost of the problems,  but now, I when I'm try to fix the last ones, I get a type of "solution" I've never seen.

I explain it:

[image]

I have this problems, when I click, in the red cross to see what solutions offers Eclipse, I choose the "Fix project setup". when I click on it, it returns me this window:

[image]

But I don't know what fits to my project. Even more, I don't know what it means.
That's how build path looks:

[image]
[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: org.apache.httpclient libraries are no longer supported in android 6.0. If you build for <= 5.x, the errors will go away, otherwise look into using HttpURLConnection

Comment: Also, if you want to stick with Marshmallow and HttpClient, adding the httpclient-4.x library should do the trick (IIRC you need that along with httpcore-4.x)